# Create image/mjpeg buffer with jquery/js or php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, buffer, mjpeg

I have an IP camera streaming mjpeg. I was originally streaming it like this:

```
//JQUERY
    setInterval(function(){
    $("#overView").attr("src", "http://74.105.102.4:9999/cgi-bin/view/image?pro_3?"+new Date().getTime());
},1000);

//HTML
    <img id="overView" class="overView" width="710" height="400" style="" src="http://74.105.102.4:9999/cgi-bin/view/image?pro_3">
```

This works fine but only gives me 1 frame per second, if I try to squeeze out any more, it stalls because I need to create a buffer. The camera settings are a max rate of 30fps. SO in order to achieve more FPS I attempted to create a buffer using jQuery like this:

```
//JQUERY
var mjpegImg = 'http://74.105.102.4:9999/cgi-bin/view/image?pro_3';

$('#start').attr('disabled', false).toggle(function() {
    $(this).text('Stop');

    $('#buffer').load(function() {
        $('#video').attr('src', this.src);
        this.src = mjpegImg + '?cache=' + new Date().getTime();
    }).trigger('load');
}, function() {
    $(this).text('Start');
    $('#buffer').unbind();
});​

//HTML
<img id="buffer" alt="" />
<img id="video" alt="" />
<button id="start" disabled="disabled">Start</button>​
```

This KIND of works, still glitchy though. Here is the fiddle of the above script
http://jsfiddle.net/XgAWJ/2/ In the top right of the stream there is a time stamp counting up so you can tell how it's moving.

Is there anyway I can squeeze out more FPS using this method? 15-20fps would be ideal. The camera is hosted from a 15mbs upload line, that should suffice for mjpeg. I am not afraid of using PHP either if theres a way to utilize the `ob_start()`, I saw a solution using that here http://ben-collins.blogspot.com/2010/06/php-sending-motion-jpeg.html Not sure if that would work right, I don't see anywhere to set a time interval.

Thanks a bunch guys!

Comment: Lowered the quality of the camera and lowering the interval of triggering the load(). Progress here: http://jsfiddle.net/XgAWJ/35/